# search for symbols in a string

Tags: php, string, strpos

I'm writing some code and need to search for some kinds of symbols in a string. I use mb_strpos function for this and it works for alphabet symbols but it doesn't if I search for symbols like question mark, dots and etc. For example if I search for "aaaaa" (or any other unicode character) in  a string mb_strpos works as expected but if I search for "?????" it doesn't!

This is my code:

```
function symbols_in_row($string, $limit=5) {
    //split string by characters and generate new array containing each character
    $symbol = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    //remove duplicate symbols from array
    $unique = array_unique($symbol);
    //generate combination of symbols and search for them in string
    for($x=0; $x<=count($unique); $x++) {
        //generate combination of symbols
        for($c=1; $c<=$limit; $c++) {
            $combination .= $unique[$x];
        }
        //search for this combination of symbols in given string
        $pos = mb_strpos($string, $combination);
        if ($pos !== false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It always returns true in second case!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Unsure about your actual use case. But array_unique() is indifferent as to the UTF-8 serialization, when preg_split didn't normalize it. It might very well split up ? and *?* and **?** if they have distinct encodings. And an input text of "isthisright???`?`?" might not be matched by "?????" (allthough this is exactly what mb_strpos is for?). And anyway I'm not sure about how $combination is going to be in $string. Does it work if you write that specific mb_strpos() match manually?

Comment: I'm confused about a few things here: 1) the $combination variable. You are concat'ing to it without ever giving it an initial value.  2) $combination doesn't ever get reset, so it will just grow and grow in your nested loop. 3) What is this function intended to do in general?  Is it true that symbols_in_row("aaa", 3) should return true, but symbols_in_row("aaa", 4) should return false?  4) If you *do* find it with mb_strpos() - why are you returning false?  Wouldn't you want to return true?

Comment: I try to explain what is this function intended to do. It should detect if a string contains any symbol more than five times in a row. For example a string "something?????" or "sommmmmthing?" should return false, otherwise it should return true.

I've set a minimum length limit in post title so users often try to meet the limit in this way...

Comment: There are some mistakes in this code. I corrected and now it works fine. Thanks for pointing the right way :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, may I suggest doing it in a different way?

```
function symbolsInRow($string, $limit = 5) {
    $regex = '/(.)\1{'.($limit - 1).',}/us';
    return 0 == preg_match($regex, $string);
}
```

So basically it just looks at any character repeated `$limit` times in a row (or more).  If it finds any, it returns `false`.  Otherwise it returns `true`...

Comment: This code has the same problem I described in the question above. For example it doesn't catch five question marks or dots in a row!

Comment: @Levani: Sure it does (I fixed a minor bug in the regex)...  If it's not for you, I'd have to question if the question marks are actually the same character... Convert the string to hex and see if they are exactly the same character...  http://dev.meagar.net/preg.php?preg=/(.)\1{4,}/us&query=abc.....&replace=

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple regExp:

```
<pre>
<?php 

$str="Lorem ipsum ?????? dolor sit amet xxxxx ? consectetuer faucibus.";
preg_match_all('@(.)\1{4,}@s',$str,$out);
print_r($out);
?>
</pre>
```

To explain the expression:

`(.)` matches every char and creates a reference to it
`\1` uses this reference
`{4,}` the reference has to occur 4 time or more(so with this 4 chars and the reference itself you will match 5 identical chars)